# Grayscale image histogram seems wrong

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to get the histogram of this 256*256 double grayscale image.
[image: Grayscale image]

This is what's displayed by `imhist(img)`:

[image: Histogram]

There is one single vertical line of height 65536 at abscissa 1. It doesn't seem right to me. Am I using `imhist` wrong?

Comment: What is a double greyscale image please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I mean a greyscale image represented as a matrix of `double`s.

Comment: But you've posted a PNG which can't store doubles?

Comment: I plotted the image with `showgrey` and saved the result as a PNG with Matlab.

Comment: Normalizing your image data, img = img/max(img(:)), should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the imhist function and I acquired a proper result for this picture's histogram.

[image: Histogram]

First I transformed it from RGB to grayscale so, the imhist can be used.
Then I plotted just by the imhist itself. 
I am using Matlab R2016a.

**As stated in Matlab help page in below link you can use the imhist to plot the histogram**
https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html

check the below code:

```
img = imread('C:\Users\farazpc.ir\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\AVWda.png');
img= rgb2gray(img);
 imhist(img)
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes. Thank you for sharing this with me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with MATLAB R2017a and the following code worked for me. Hope it help you as well...

```
I=imread('111.png');
imhist(I)
title('Histogram without rgb2gray function in MATLAB')
%%
I=rgb2gray(I);
figure
imhist(I)
title('Histogram with rgb2gray function in MATLAB')
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are right. I just changed the name and copied it to my current directory to get rid of a bad path address :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html#buo3qvv-1):

> For grayscale images, the n bins of the histogram are each half-open intervals of width A/(n−1).

... where A is 1 for double arrays. That is, for your double array, bin widths are 1/(n-1), with n bins, leading to a range of [0,1].

This is MATLAB's implicit range for images stored in a double array. Every time you use a double array as an image, MATLAB assumes its max value is 1.

You can tell from the x-axis of the histogram.

However, you image likely has larger values, which then all end up in the top bin.

One solution is to, when you read in the image, convert it to doubles using [`im2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html).

Another solution is to use the [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) function, rather than `imhist`. This function is much more flexible and general, and makes much better histograms. It will plot a histogram over the full range of the data by default.